# Agora.io User can't display the other user but can send self image and display it

Tags: agora.io

I am using Agora SDK on web, it works completely fine on Google Chrome and Firefox browsers on macOS and windows, but on Safari, the user can send his own image and he can also sees himself but he can't see the person he is in videocall with.

Answer (score 0):

Agora's Web SDK leverages the WebRTC API, and for this reason Safari browser has some limitations. Your question does not include much detail or code, so its difficult to make a definitive diagnosis, but the issue sounds like the browser autoplay policy is blocking the remote video stream from playing. Usually the autoplay policy does not affect the local streams (because the local streams  do not play the local audio), so you only need to deal with the remote streams.

There are two options for working around the autoplay policy.

1. Bypass the autoplay block when the playback fails.
   When detecting an autoplay block, instruct the user to click on the webpage to resume the playback:

```js
 stream.play("agora_remote"+ stream.getId(), function(err){
         if (err && err.status !== "aborted"){
                // The playback fails. Guide the user to resume the playback by clicking.            
                document.querySelector("#agora_remote"+ stream.getId()).onclick=function(){
                         stream.resume().then(
                         function (result) {
                               console.log('Resume succeeds: ' + result);
                        }).catch(
                         function (reason) {
                               console.log('Resume fails: ' + reason);
                        });
                }      
        }
 });
```

2. Bypass the autoplay block in advance.
   If you prefer dealing with the autoplay block in advance, choose one of the following methods:

- **Method one:** Play the stream without sound first by Stream.play("ID", { muted: true }), because autoplay without sound is allowed.
- **Method two:** In your UI design, instruct the user to interact with the webpage, either by clicking or touching, to play the stream.

For more details about the two implementations for bypassing the autoplay policy ahead in advance, I would recommend taking a look at [Agora's "Deal with autoplay policy" guide](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/autoplay_policy_web?platform=Web#handle-autoplay-policy-on-ios-safari-or-webview).